# C#, WPF DataGrid displays empty rows

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I am trying to make WPF UI for my application, and got stuck on binding a BindingList to a DataGrid.
It displays rows according to the amount of items in the list, but the cells are empty

Changing collection type to List or ObservableCollection has yielded no results

MainWindow.xaml - DataGrid code

```
        <DataGrid x:Name="DataGrid1" Grid.Column="1" CanUserResizeRows="False" CanUserResizeColumns="False" ColumnWidth="*" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
            <DataGrid.Resources>
                <DataTemplate x:Key="ButtonCellTemplate">
                    <DataGridCell>
                        <Button x:Name="EditButton" Click="EditButton_Click">Edit</Button>
                    </DataGridCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGrid.Resources>
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Command" Binding="{Binding Command}"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Description" Binding="{Binding Description}"/>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn Width="Auto" CellTemplate="{StaticResource ButtonCellTemplate}"/>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
```

MainWindow.xaml.cs

```
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            VoiceApp.LoadData("Elite.xml");
            DataGrid1.ItemsSource = VoiceApp.commands;
        }
    }
```

`VoiceApp.commands` is a `public static BindingList<VoiceCommand> commands { get; set; }`

VoiceCommand.cs

```
public class VoiceCommand
    {
        public string Command { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public BindingList<KeyAction> actions = new BindingList<KeyAction>();
}
```

VoiceApp.cs

```
    public static class VoiceApp
    {
        static readonly CultureInfo eng = new CultureInfo("en-US");
        public static SpeechRecognitionEngine recognitionEngine = new SpeechRecognitionEngine(eng);

        public static BindingList<VoiceCommand> commands { get; set; } = new BindingList<VoiceCommand>();
        public static void ActivateRecognition()
        {
            Choices choices = new Choices(commands.Select(x => x.Command).ToArray());
            GrammarBuilder grammarBuilder = new GrammarBuilder(choices);
            grammarBuilder.Culture = eng;
            Grammar grammar = new Grammar(grammarBuilder);
            recognitionEngine.LoadGrammar(grammar);
            recognitionEngine.SetInputToDefaultAudioDevice();
            recognitionEngine.RecognizeAsync(RecognizeMode.Multiple);
        }
        public static void DeactivateRecognition()
        {
            recognitionEngine.RecognizeAsyncStop();
        }
        public static void SaveData(string path = "testSave.xml")
        {
            var ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<VoiceCommand>));
            var saveData = commands.ToList();
            var writer = new FileStream(Path.ChangeExtension(path, "xml"), FileMode.Create);
            ser.Serialize(writer, saveData);
        }
        public static void LoadData(string path = "testSave.xml")
        {
            var ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<VoiceCommand>));
            var reader = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open);
            commands = new BindingList<VoiceCommand>(ser.Deserialize(reader) as List<VoiceCommand>);
        }
    }
```

Comment: "*cells are empty*" - but you have assigned values to the Command and Description properties of the items?

Comment: Can you show a complete code where we can see what is `VoiceApp` and how its `commands` get assigned, etc?

Comment: Are there any log outputs that said your Bindings failed ?

Comment: VoiceApp.commands works just fine in WinForms variant of the UI

Answer (score 0):

The issue was with the saved file itself, as properties were saved under different names. Fixing them solved the issue.